# How to include Transactions from a single User

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to do a get a user, including all of his transactions from another table.  There is a one to many relationship between user and transactions.  How do I include my transactions when I get the user?

```
public class User{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        public string FirstName{get;set;}
        public string LastName{get;set;}
        public string Email{get;set;}
        public string Password{get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public List<Transaction> Transactions{get;set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public string ConfirmPassword{get;set;}
    }

#Controller
[HttpGet("account")]
        public IActionResult Account(){
            User user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("user"))
                .Include(u => u.Transactions);

            return View("account", user);
        }
```

I just want the transactions to be included with the user when passed to the view.  I don't understand how to do this.  Right now it is telling me that "User does not contain a definition for include"  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: do `FirstOrDefault` after `Include`

Comment: Wow, that was it...  I feel pretty dumb now.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 : 
You must include related tables before Executing Query on IQueryable like this :

```
var userId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("user");

User user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.id == userId)
    .Include(u => u.Transactions)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Solution 2 : 
You can select a User that have List of Transactions for that user like this:

```
var userId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("user");

User user = _context.Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(u => u.id == userId)
    .Select(u => new User
    {
        //Select all properties like this :
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        //... Other properties,
        Transactions = u.TransActions.Select(t => new TransationViewModel
        {
            //Select all properties like this :
            //Name = t.Name
        }).ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.  New to Linq and still trying to get it down.  This will be a great reference for me going forward.  I appreciate it.